# Logistic Regression in R - Interpreting interaction effects for categorical variables

Tags: r, logistic-regression, categorical-data, interaction

I have a dataset that looks like this.

[image]

Note that variable A and B are binary variables of Low/High 
The following code has been run in R

```
logit = glm(y ~ A*B , family = binomial(link='logit') , data=df)
summary(logit)
```

and here's the output
[image]

The reason for including the interaction effect between A and B is my hypothesis does NOT align with the effect of A and B so I thought I'd include the interaction effect between A and B and not surprisingly it turned out to be quite significant. 
But how do I interpret these coefficients? 
I know how to interpret if either A or B was numeric but dealing with 2 categorical variables is quite hard to get my head around.

Looking forward to some expert's advices/comments.

Many thanks!

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This is probably more appropriate for stats.stackexchange.com but basically this is saying that the effect of A on whether y is Terminated depends on B (or equivalently, the effect of B on y depends on A). If A is low, the effect of B being low is more strongly pushing y toward being Terminated. Note: my interpretation is based on all your factors in the dataframe having R's default alphabetical ordering so that active = 0, terminated = 1 for y, and high = 0, low = 1 for A and B (I'm assuming you didn't change that).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, now that I'm thinking about it, you're right, I should've posted this on stats.stackexchange.com. Having said that, your comment is very useful and I'd like to validate something. When you say that if A is low, the effect of B being low is more strongly pushing y towards Terminated, is your comment based on the fact that the interaction coefficient is 1.4142? If yes, does that mean if interaction coefficient was -ve, would it be fair for me to say, given A is low the effect of B being low is drifting away from y being terminated?

Comment: Yes because if high = 0 and low = 1, then Alow * Blow is 1*1 = 1. If you multiply 1*1*positive number, you get a positive effect (and if terminated =1, positive means higher probability of terminated). If you multiply 1*1*negative number, you get a negative effect on the probability of terminated.

Comment: So if the interaction was < 0, that would mean if A is low, B being low has a weaker effect on the probability of termination. Or if the magnitude of the interaction effect is bigger than the main effect, the interaction could even mean that B causes the overall effect of A to flip from positive to negative. But all of that is not what we observe here because your interaction is >0.

Comment: Don't forget that all results from logistic regression is in log-odds.

Comment: Thank you all so much for useful comments!! :)

Comment: @qdread, please post your comments as an answer? (This can get migrated to CrossValidated if enough high-rep users vote to do it ...)

Comment: Will do shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### General background: interpreting logistic regression coefficients

First of all, to learn more about interpreting logistic regression coefficients generally, take a look at [this guide for beginners](https://quantifyinghealth.com/interpret-logistic-regression-coefficients/). Logistic regression coefficients are the change in log odds of the outcome associated with an increase of 1 unit in the predictor variable. So if you have a coefficient `\beta` you can exponentiate it, `exp(beta)` to get the odds ratio. If `beta = 0`, `exp(beta) = 1` so the OR is 1 and the predictor variable has no effect on the odds of the response. If `beta > 0`, the OR is positive and the predictor variable increases the odds of the response if it increases.

### Interpreting interaction coefficients on categorical variables in R logistic regressions

Now that we have that background, we can proceed to a more specific answer to the question here.

In R, linear models like `glm()` with categorical predictor variables use the `factor` data type for those variables. If they are in character format when you pass them to `glm()`, it will coerce them to factors. Then after that coercion, the model converts each factor to a set of `n-1` dummy variables where `n` is the number of unique levels in the factor. The default ordering is alphabetical, so a factor level coming first in the alphabet will be treated as the reference or intercept level.

Therefore because `A` and `B` each have only two unique levels, and `High` comes before `Low` in the alphabet, both `A` and `B` will essentially be converted to a single vector of `0` and `1` where High is `0` and Low is `1`. You can change this behavior by manually setting the factor level ordering: `df$A <- factor(df$A, levels = c('Low', 'High'))`.

In your model, the coefficient on the interaction between `A` and `B` is saying how strongly the effect of `A` on whether `y` is `Terminated` depends on `B` (or equivalently, the effect of `B` on `y` depends on `A`). Note this also assumes that the `y` outcome variable, which is binary, has `Active = 0` and `Terminated = 1`. This is also because of the default alphabetical ordering.

The model is
[image]

Because A is either 0 or 1 and B is either 0 or 1, the last term in that equation above will be 0 unless both A=1 and B=1. That corresponds to both variables being `Low` assuming you're using the default factor coding. We can interpret the coefficient of 1.41, which is positive, as saying that if `A` is `Low`, the effect of `B` on `y` is more positive, or causing a greater increase in the probability of `y` being `Terminated`. Specifically, if both are `Low`, the odds of `Terminated` are about `exp(1.41) = 4.1` times higher than if at least one of them isn't `Low`.

You can say "if A is Low, then B being Low has a positive effect on the probability of termination, but if A is High, then B being Low has a negative effect on the probability of termination." That's because the main effect of B is < 0 while the interaction coefficient is > 0.